# Google Cloud Organisation Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I have recently changed the primary domain of the company's G Suite account.

The Organisation name in Google Cloud hasn't updated to our new domain, I have tried following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599888/how-do-i-rename-a-google-cloud-platform-project/34601514), however it didn't work and the Organisation name isn't editable.

Can I force an update?

Comment: As a G Suite administrator, you've got 24/7 phone access, which is a rare treat in Google-world. I'd give 'em a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contact G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), outlining the steps you've done so far, and ask them to open a case to have this done by GCP Support.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.

I didn't think I could use G Suite support for Google Cloud Platform.

It was ultimately down to propagation.

Comment: @JacobWoffenden Usually you can't, but the organizations are one and the same (tl;dr: same backend), so the support available to you was able to deal with it. (They would have escalated it to us if need be.)

Comment: @JacobWoffenden Welcome to ServerFault! Please both upvote **and** accept a correct answer. :)

Comment: I can't upvote as I've got less than 15 reputation. I've marked as answered.